# why return value of a method is not accessable inside another method

Tags: methods, return-value, attributeerror

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,student_id,marks,age):
        self.__student_id=student_id
        self.__marks=marks
        self.__age=age

    def set_student_id(self,student_id):
        self.__student_id=student_id

    def set_marks(self,marks):
        self.__marks=marks

    def set_age(self,age):
        self.__age=age

    def get_student_id(self):
        return self.__student_id    

    def get_marks(self):
        return self.__marks 

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age

    def validate_age(self):
        return True if self.__age>20 else False

    def check_qualification(self):
        a=validate_marks(self)
        if a==True:
            return True if self.__marks>=65 else False
        else:
            return False

    def validate_marks(self):
        return True if self.__marks in range(0,101) else False


a=Student(4,89,22)       
a.check_qualification()        
shows error help to fix it
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing problem where you tried to call validate_marks method.

```
def validate_age(self):
    return self.__age > 20

def check_qualification(self):
    return self.validate_marks() and self.validate_age() and self.__marks >= 65

def validate_marks(self):
    return self.__marks in range(0, 101)
```

Usage will look like

```
james = Student(12, 79, 25) # 12 - Student ID, 79 Marks & 25 Age
james.check_qualification() # True or False based on validation
```

Comment: thanks for helping me.it works nicely.can you please explain how our check_qualification() methods are different?

Comment: You are trying to pass self as an argument, but you need to use self to call other instance methods. If you find the answer working you can accept it.

Comment: can i call set_age(age) inside check_qualification()?  i mean how to call a method which use parameters inside another method.

Comment: The usage is like self.set_age(age).

Comment: do i need to ask value of age inside the check_qualification() method?  otherwise what would be the input ? how a.check_qualification() will get the value of age?

Comment: Check the edits for the answer. And you still have doubts please go through https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp